# Tensorflow embedding_lookup

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, word-embedding

I am trying to learn the word representation of the imdb dataset "from scratch" through the TensorFlow `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` function. If I understand it correctly, I have to set up an embedding layer before the other hidden layer, and then when I perform gradient descent, the layer will "learn" a word representation in the weights of this layer. However, when I try to do this, I get a shape error between my embedding layer and the first fully-connected layer of my network.

```
def multilayer_perceptron(_X, _weights, _biases):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):
        W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),name="W")
        embedding_layer = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, _X)    
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(embedding_layer, _weights['h1']), _biases['b1'])) 
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, _weights['h2']), _biases['b2'])) 
    return tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred,y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.3).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: Shapes TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(300), Dimension(128)])
and TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]) must have the same rank
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The shape error arises because you are using a two-dimensional tensor, `x` to index into a two-dimensional embedding tensor `W`. Think of [`tf.nn.embedding_lookup()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup) (and its close cousin [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather)) as taking each integer value `i` in `x` and replacing it with the row `W[i, :]`. From the error message, one can infer that `n_input = 300` and `embedding_size = 128`. In general, the result of `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` number of dimensions equal to `rank(x) + rank(W) - 1`… in this case, 3. The error arises when you try to multiply this result by `_weights['h1']`, which is a (two-dimensional) matrix.

To fix this code, it depends on what you're trying to do, and why you are passing in a matrix of inputs to the embedding. One common thing to do is to *aggregate* the embedding vectors for each input example into a single row per example using an operation like [`tf.reduce_sum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum). For example, you might do the following:

```
W = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0) ,name="W")
embedding_layer = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, _X)

# Reduce along dimension 1 (`n_input`) to get a single vector (row)
# per input example.
embedding_aggregated = tf.reduce_sum(embedding_layer, [1])

layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(
    embedding_aggregated, _weights['h1']), _biases['b1']))
```

Comment: Thanks ! I think tf.nn.reduce_sum should be tf.reduce_sum  ? When you choose to reduce the dimension of the embedding layer, how did you choose the one to reduce between "n_input=300" and "embedding_size=128" ?

Comment: You're right about the typo - corrected it above, thanks! I chose to reduce along the `n_input` dimension because it seemed more likely that that would match your problem, and I assumed that (e.g.) the order of inputs was not important. It's fairly typical to do this for bag-of-words type problems. You *could* reduce along `embedding_size` but I think that would lose a lot of information from the embedding, so it probably wouldn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

One another possible solution is : Instead of adding the embedding vectors, concatenate these vectors into a single vector and increase the number of neurons in the hidden layer. 
I used : 
    `embedding_aggregated = tf.reshape(embedding_layer, [-1, embedding_size *     sequence_length])` 
Also, i changed the number of neurons in hidden layer to `embedding_size * sequence_length`. 
Observation : Accuracy also improved on using concatenation rather than addition.